# Display certain modal or picture based on multiple criteria

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to know how, in the most simple way (because I am. My knowledge is basic of HTML, Bootstrap, and basic CSS), I can do the following:

'If radio button #1 is clicked, radio button #4 is clicked, and normal button #2 is clicked, then on submit: display modal (with picture inside) 1 in part x of the page'

'If radio button #1 is clicked, radio button #2 is clicked, and normal button #7 is clicked, then on submit: display modal (with picture inside) 23 in part x of the page'

I have the feeling this should be possible with Bootstrap but I can't really figure it out right now. Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Taken from the Bootstrap modal [documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/) itself:

> Have a bunch of buttons that all trigger the same modal with slightly
>   different contents? Use event.relatedTarget and HTML data-* attributes
>   (possibly via jQuery) to vary the contents of the modal depending on
>   which button was clicked.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-whatever="@mdo">Open modal for @mdo</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-whatever="@fat">Open modal for @fat</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-whatever="@getbootstrap">Open modal for @getbootstrap</button>

<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">New message</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Recipient:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="recipient-name">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="message-text" class="col-form-label">Message:</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" id="message-text"></textarea>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Send message</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

$('#exampleModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
  var button = $(event.relatedTarget) // Button that triggered the modal
  var recipient = button.data('whatever') // Extract info from data-* attributes
  // If necessary, you could initiate an AJAX request here (and then do the updating in a callback).
  // Update the modal's content. We'll use jQuery here, but you could use a data binding library or other methods instead.
  var modal = $(this)
  modal.find('.modal-title').text('New message to ' + recipient)
  modal.find('.modal-body input').val(recipient)
})
```

Given that we don't know specifically what you want to load, you should modify this to meet your needs.